# Mode on a specific axis in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, frequency

**Goal**

Given a list of images, I'd like to create a new image where each pixel contains the values (R,G,B) that occurred most frequently in the input list at that location.

**Details**

Input: A list L that has length >=2. Each image/object in the list is a float32 numpy array with dimensions (288, 512, 3) where 3 represents the R/G/B color channels.

Output: A numpy array with the same shape (288,512,3). If there is no pixel that occurred most frequently, any of the pixels for that location can be returned.

**Attempt**

```
image = stats.mode(L)[0][0]
```

The problem with this approach is that it looks at each R/G/B value of a pixel individually. But I want a pixel to only be considered the same as another pixel if all the color channels match (i.e. R1=R2, G1=G2, B1=B2).

Comment: What's the input shape? Is the input an array?

Comment: @Divakar a list of 10 images where each image is [100,100,3]

Comment: If `imgs` is the input list, I think : `mode(imgs)[0][0]`, with [SciPy mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html).

Comment: I think that'll give the mode of each color channel, @Divakar.  You'd need to pack up the RGB dimension first, maybe with `np.left_shift(imgs, [0, 8, 16]).sum(-1)`

Comment: @DanielF that makes sense - just got some weird results and that explains it. Can you explain where you get [0, 8, 16] from?

Comment: Basically it's just packing 3 x 8-bit integers into a single 24-bit integer by offsetting the `G` and `B` channels by `8` and `16` bits respectively.  There's probably a faster way, but it's the simplest I can think of.

Comment: What is the expected output if there is no mode (i.e. all values are unique?)

Comment: @DanielF got it. if all values are unique, return the mean of the each R/G/B coordinate for that pixel.

Comment: @Divakar that worked. I did realize I want to look at pixels as one (their combined R/G/B values), not individually. do you know how to adjust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def packRGB(RGB):
    return np.left_shift(RGB, [0, 8, 16]).sum(-1)

def unpackRGB(i24):
    B = np.right_shift(i24, 16)
    G = np.right_shift(i24, 8) - np.left_shift(B, 8)
    R = i24 - np.left_shift(G, 8) - np.left_shift(B, 16)
    return np.stack([R, G, B]).T

def img_mode(imgs_list, average_singles = True):
    imgs = np.array(imgs_list) #(10, 100, 100, 3)
    imgs24 = packRGB(imgs) # (10, 100, 100)
    mode, count = scipy.stats.mode(imgs24, axis = 0) # (1, 100,100)
    mode, count = mode.squeeze(), count.squeeze()  #(100, 100)
    if average_singles:
        out = np.empty(imgs.shape[1:])
        out[count == 1] = np.rint(np.average(imgs[:, count == 1], axis = 0))
        out[count > 1] = unpackRGB(mode[count > 1])
    else:
        out = unpackRGB(mode)
    return out
```

EDIT: fixed error and added option from your other question:  Aany value in set  if no mode, which should be faster due to no division or rounding.  `scipy.stats.mode` returns lowest value, which in this case will be the pixel with the lowest blue value.  You also might want to try `median`, as `mode` is going to be unstable to very small differences in the inputs (especially if there are only ten)

This will also be a lot slower than, for instance, Photoshop's statistics function (I assume you're trying to do something like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/LifeProTips/comments/6uei5z/lpt_delete_tourists_from_your_travel_photos/dls2y5z/)), as you'd want to parallel-ize the function as well to make it time efficient.

Comment: I get an error on out[count == 1] = np.rint(np.average(imgs[:, count == 1], axis = 0)). It's "IndexError: index 33 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 3". 
 Also this step works but takes several minutes to execute. mode, count = scipy.stats.mode(imgs24, axis = 0)

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is without the inputs and outputs you are using.  Did you input a list of arrays or only one?

Comment: I inputted a list of numpy arrays, each with shape (288,512,3). The list has length 10.

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. Going to look into parallelizing because like you said scipy.stats.mode runs extremely slowly.